# Bold content takes longer to load

Tags: css, angular, fonts

I have an Angular application with a page that contains:

```
<p>Text<span class="bold">Bold text</span><p>
```

The bold class is defined as

```
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

When the page loads, 'Text' first appears, and then 'Bold text' appears.
If I apply any other css class to the span this problem doesn't happen, it has something to do with the fonts but I can't figure out what is happening and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid including font cdn or specifying `font-weight:bold` .
Download your required font from google fonts site. It will give you choice to download various styles of same fonts. i.e italic, bold, semibold, etc.

When you use this method it does not take time to load your fonts and your issue will be solved.